# How to access the particular child from all the children of a parent in firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: This is is firebase database structure]

I want to access the highlighted values of child from all the children of "services" in the attached image and store them in an array. Help me to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void getData(){
    DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Services");
    database_course.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String key = ds.getKey(); //"AC Repair","Fridge Repair"
                HashMap<String, HashMap<String,HashMap<String,Object>>> servicesHashMap = ds.get(key);
                //Icon Source
                String imageUrl = (String) servicesHashMap.get(key).get("Icon Source").get("imageUrl");
                String name = (String) servicesHashMap.get(key).get("Icon Source").get("name");
                //Rate Card
                HashMap<String,Object> serviceType = (HashMap<String, Object>) servicesHashMap.get(key).get("Rate Card").get("serviceType1");
                int  price = (int) serviceType.get("price");//if price is 1300
                //int  price = (int) serviceType.get("price");//if price is "1300"
                String type = (String)serviceType.get("type");
                //Service Image
                HashMap<String, Object> url = servicesHashMap.get("Service Image").get("url");

            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```